# Java: How to get milliseconds in timestamp

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new java.util.Date());
```

I tried this:

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss.ms").format(new java.util.Date());
```

But it didn't give me milliseconds. What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to do this, or is it impossible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you read the JavaDoc on `SimpleDateFormat` you'll see that for milliseconds you need `SSS`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Milliseconds are represented by the capital `S`:

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss.SSS").format(new java.util.Date());
```